# Google Earth Engine Creating a mask for an ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, masking, evi

I'm using Google Earth Engine's JavaScript API to process Sentinel-2 images. I've calculated the EVI from the Sentinel ImageCollection, and would like to apply a mask that removes all the values outside the range of -1 to 1. However, I don't know how to create a mask for an ImageCollection rather than a single image.

My code so far is:

```
//make EVI expression into a function
var addEVI=function(image){
var EVI = image.expression(
      '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR' : image.select('B8').divide(10000),
      'RED' : image.select('B4').divide(10000),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000)}).rename('EVI');
      return image.addBands(EVI);
};

//get full dataset
var collectionfull= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
            .filterBounds(studyarea)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50));

//map EVI across full dataset
var calculatedfull=collectionfull.map(addEVI);

//mapping selecting only EVI band across full dataset
var evifull =calculatedfull.select('EVI');

//applying mask (focus of question)
var maskposi = evifull.select('EVI').gt(1);
print('Mask positive', maskposi);
Map.addLayer(maskposi, 'mask positive');
```

This code, when run, produces the error `evifull.select(...).gt is not a function.`

How do I make a mask that will work for an ImageCollection?

Answer (score 1):

You also map over the image collection. Just like with the `addEVI` function you have.

Basically if you know how to do the operation for a single Image, most of the time it is very easy to write a mapped function for an entire image collection.

For a single image you can apply a mask something like this, calling `.mask()` on the image and supplying it with a binary classification:

```
var test_image = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200102T111349_20200102T111435_T30UXB")

// Let's mask everything that is a cloud
var masked = test_image.mask(test_image.select("SCL").eq(9))
```

Now if we want to mask every Image in an Image Collection we use the same code but generalize it and put it into the function to map over:

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point([-0.8, 50.9])).limit(10)

var s2_masked = s2.map(function(image){
  // Here comes the same code as for a single Image, 
  // but only replacing the specific variable `test_image` from before with the
  // general parameter `image` that we just specified as the parameter of
  // this function
  return image.mask(image.select("SCL").eq(9))
})

Map.addLayer(s2_masked)
```

Mapping a function over an image collection basically means "Apply those commands to every image in this collection"